# How to call ajax only when show detail on vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I have two component. I set and get data by vuex store

My first component like this :

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li v-for="item in getOrderList" class="list-group-item">
            ....
                    <a href="javascript:"
                       class="toggle-show"
                       aria-expanded="false"
                       data-toggle="collapse"
                       :data-target="'#' + item.id"
                       @click="showDetailOrder(item.id)">
                        Show <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
            ...
            <div class="collapse" :id="item.id">
                <template v-if="getOrderDetail.id">
                    <order-collapse/>
                </template>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
    import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'
    import OrderCollapse from './OrderCollapse.vue'
    export default {
        name: 'order-list',
        components: {OrderCollapse},
        created() {
            // this is ajax to get order list. process ajax in the vuex store. this return data orders
            this.setOrderList()
        }
        methods: {
            ...mapActions(['setOrderList']),
            showDetailOrder(id) {
                // this is ajax to get order detail by id. process ajax in the vuex store. this return detail order by id
                this.setOrderDetail(id)
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getOrderList'])
        },
    }
</script>
```

My second component like this :

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-collapse">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="title">Address<br></span>
                <span class="title">{{getOrderDetail.buyer.name}}</span>
                <p>
                    {{getOrderDetail.buyer.address}}<br>
                    {{getOrderDetail.buyer.mobile_number}}<br>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
    export default {
        name: 'order-collapse',
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getOrderDetail'])
        },
    }
</script>
```

Note :

`setOrderList()`: this will call ajax and save the response(orders data list) on : getOrderList
`setOrderDetail()`: this will call ajax and save the response(order data by id) on : getOrderDetail

Every time you click the button show, it will call ajax

If clicking the button show, it will show detail order by id

if clicking button show again, it will hide detail order by id

I want when hide detail order, it does not call ajax

So it only calls ajax if you want to show detail order

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you try using v-if on the button if details are there?

Comment: @Saurabh It still does not work. Because I have a lot of order data. For example there are 2 data order. If I click show on first order data. It will call ajax and display details of the first order data. Then I click show again it does not call ajax and hide detail order from first order data. My problem is when I click show on second order data. It does not call ajax and it shows details of order from first order data. Should if I click show on second order data. It will call ajax and display detail order of the second order data

Comment: Can you add that relevant code or if from dummy data reproduce it in a jsfiddle, it will be helpful for community to help you.

Comment: @Saurabh It seems that I have shown the required codes. If there's too much code, it can not make a question. So I provide the necessary codes only. I use vuex store and ajax axios. It can not use jsfiddle

Comment: I agree with @Saurabh, there seems to be multiple methods missing there. In any case, I would not add more code to the component. Also, your naming is misleading - having 'get' in front of code in the template which is really an object.